# Using xlrd to get list of excel values in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to read a list of values in a column in an excel sheet.  However, the length of the column varies every time, so I don't know the length of the list.  How do I get python to read all the values in a column and stop when the cells are empty using xlrd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(worksheet.nrows):
```

will iterate through all the rows in the worksheet

if you were interested in column 0 for example

```
c0 = [worksheet.row_values(i)[0] for i in range(worksheet.nrows) if worksheet.row_values(i)[0]]
```

or even better make this a generator

```
column_generator = (worksheet.row_values(i)[0] for i in range(worksheet.nrows))
```

then you can use itertools.takewhile for lazy evaluations... that will stop when you get your first empty... this will provide better performance if you just want to stop once you get your first empty value

```
from itertools import takewhile
print list(takewhile(str.strip,column_generator))
```

Comment: Thanks- but how do I get it to stop when the cells are empty?  That gets me all of the cells in the column, even the empty ones.